# Trying to Connect Four

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple connect four game with 2d arrays. I'm having a little trouble with making the grid. Here's what the final outcome should look like.

```
||||||||

||||||||

||||||||

|||R|||||

||||||||

||||||||

||||||||
```

Here's my code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Connect{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);

    String[] [] v=new String[7] [15];

    for(int i=0 ; i<v.length ; i++){
        for(int l=0 ; l<v[i].length ; l++){
            if (l%2 == 0){
                v[i] [l]="|";
            }else{
                v[i] [l]="";
            }
            if (i==6) 
                v[i][l]="-".
       }
   }
}

public static void print(String[] [] v){
    for(int i=0 ; i<v.length ; i++){
        for (int l=0 ; l<v[i].length ; l++){
            System.out.print(v[i][l]); 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: Could you give your output that you're getting? I don't want to run your code for you.

Comment: My question is how can I get the design up top.  I need a 2d array to fill with input.  But I can't get the visual down.

Comment: What is the input required to have that output ?

Comment: @Tillix Why would you want that output? Shouldn't there be a space between the vertical lines, so they'd always line up?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way to achieve the desired format:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Connect{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);

        String[] [] v=new String[7] [15];

        for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++){

            for(int l=0;l<v[i].length;l++){

                if (l%2==0){
                    v[i] [l]="|";
                }
                else{
                    v[i] [l]="";
                }
            }

        }
        print(v);

   }

   public static void print(String[] [] v){
        for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++){
            for (int l=0;l<v[i].length;l++){
                System.out.print(v[i] [l]);

            }
            System.out.println('\n');
        }
   }

 }
```

Output:

```
||||||||

||||||||

||||||||

||||||||

||||||||

||||||||

||||||||
```

You have to call `print(v)` after you assign values to `v`. Notice that the condition `if (i==6) v[i][l]="-";` is removed from the loop.